# Video as background with overlayed elements

Tags: html, css

**Goal:** 
Add a video as background using HTML and CSS only.

The idea here is to have a video running in a loop that doesn't allow any interaction with the user as a background.

In front of the video i want some elements. Some text...

**The issue**
With this code:
Everything seems to be working as intended but one thing:
The video is in front of everything else. How do i put it behind the other elements?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="home" class="home3">
      <video style="width: 100%" src="video/bg_video.mov" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true">
        <div class="home-text-wrapper">
          <div class="sixteen columns">           
            <div class="home-logo-text">
              <a href="#about">Hevar</a>
            </div>
          </div>   
            <a href="#about">    
              <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="home-quote">
                  <h1>
                    <span class="slabtext">some text</span>
                    <span class="slabtext">some text</span>
                    <span class="slabtext second-child"> some text</span>      
                    <span class="slabtext">some text</span>
                  </h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>   
        </div>
        </video>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
#home {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: table;
color: #010101;
z-index:10;

.home3 .home-text-wrapper .container {
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
overflow: hidden;
}

.home3 .home-text-wrapper .container.no-safari {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.home3 .home-quote {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
height: inherit;
text-align: center;
width: inherit;
overflow: hidden;
color: white;
}
.home3 .slabtextdone {
color: #ffffff;
}
.home3 .slabtextdone .slabtext.second-child {
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
color: steelblue;
text-shadow: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
.home3 .home-text-wrapper .container:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.09);
-moz-transform: scale(1.09);
-o-transform: scale(1.09);
-ms-transform: scale(1.09);
transform: scale(1.09);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
overflow: hidden;
}
.home3#home h1 {
font-size: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: right now, the video is infront of everything which leads to it covering everything.

Comment: you can give it position relative and then use z-index on it, the video that is. Also you could remove those elements from the video tag and position them over the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
video{
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And fix your HTML:

```
<video></video>
rest code <div></div>
```

Comment: Almost there, the only problem now is that the video isn't centered. And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Guarana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632617/guarana) and[floor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3412090/floor)!

This solved it:

```
.video_bg {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: -100;
}
```